# Contact Form 7 coupon codes with ACF

Tags: wordpress

I would like to create a list of answers codes in CF7 using ACF.
I created 2 custom field inside a Page (code_1 and code_2).
Then I have created this function to validate the answers and it works but I cannot figure with custom fields

```
//Coupon Code CF7
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text', 'your_validation_filter_func', 999, 2);
 add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'your_validation_filter_func', 999, 2);
 function your_validation_filter_func($result, $tag) {

    $type = $tag['type'];
    $name = $tag['name'];
    if ('coupon_code' == $name) {
    $the_value = $_POST[$name];
    if($the_value != "abc" && $the_value != "def" && $the_value != "xyz" ){
     $result->invalidate($tag, wpcf7_get_message('invalid_coupon_code'));
     }
   }
  return $result;
}

add_filter('wpcf7_messages', 'customwpcf7_text_messages');

function customwpcf7_text_messages($messages) {
    return array_merge($messages, array(
'invalid_coupon_code' => array(
     'description' => __("Coupon invalido", 'contact-form-7'),
     'default' => __('Coupon invalido.', 'contact-form-7')
  )));
  }
```

The values "abc" "def" and "xyz" are validated but if i use this code:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text', 'your_validation_filter_func', 999, 2);
 add_filter('wpcf7_validate_text*', 'your_validation_filter_func', 999, 2);
 function your_validation_filter_func($result, $tag) {

    $type = $tag['type'];
    $name = $tag['name'];
    if ('coupon_code' == $name) {
    $the_value = $_POST[$name];
    if($the_value != the_field('codice_1') && $the_value != the_field('codice_2') && $the_value != the_field('codice_3') ){
     $result->invalidate($tag, wpcf7_get_message('invalid_coupon_code'));
     }
   }
  return $result;
}

add_filter('wpcf7_messages', 'customwpcf7_text_messages');

function customwpcf7_text_messages($messages) {
    return array_merge($messages, array(
'invalid_coupon_code' => array(
     'description' => __("Coupon invalido", 'contact-form-7'),
     'default' => __('Coupon invalido.', 'contact-form-7')
  )));
  }
```

This does not work...
can someone help me?

Comment: Please explain what `the_field('codice_1')` is and how it is defined. as far as i can see this is the only difference in your code